# Problem extending a Magento core class

Tags: magento-1.8, overrides

I am trying to extend the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` class in `app/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php`

To do that I declared a new module in `app/etc/modules/Fkoessler_myProduct.xml`:

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Fkoessler_MyProduct>
      <active>true</active>
      <codepool>local</codepool>
    </Fkoessler_MyProduct>
  </modules>
</config>
```

I created a `app/code/local/Fkoessler/MyProduct/Block/Product/View.php` file:

```
<?php
class FKoessler_MyProduct_Block_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
{
    protected function _prepareLayout(){}
}
```

and finally I created the `app/code/local/Fkoessler/MyProduct/etc/config.xml` file:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Fkoessler_MyProduct>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Fkoessler_MyProduct>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_view>Fkoessler_MyProduct_Block_Product_View</product_view>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

However it doesn't seem to be taken into account: the product view page still uses the prepareLayout as defined in the Magento core class.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I finally managed to use my own code. The problem was in the `FKoessler_MyProduct_Block_Product_View` class itself.

When I extend `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` and redefine its `_prepareLayout()` method, it is still the `_prepareLayout()` method from the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` class that gets used. That is what was confusing me.

So I changed to `extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`, copied the whole `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` class code in my `FKoessler_MyProduct_Block_Product_View` class and applied customizations. And it's working fine like that.

```
class FKoessler_MyProduct_Block_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
   // copy code from Mage_Catalog_Bliock_Product_View in here
   // and customize to your needs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are simple few issues in config.

`<rewrite`  is not close it should be `<rewrite>`  in config.xml

and   `codepool` should be  `codePool`(`p` should be **P**) at **Fkoessler_myProduct.xml**

```
 <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite
                    <product_view>Fkoessler_MyProduct_Block_Product_View</product_view>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
```

**should be**
.....

```
    <blocks>
    <catalog>
        <rewrite>
            <product_view>Fkoessler_MyProduct_Block_Product_View</product_view>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog>
</blocks>
```

**Module location is wrong:**

it should be

```
app/code/local/(code folder is missing)
```

Comment: The `<rewrite>` was properly closed in my code and was a typo in this question, so I edited the question. I changed `<codepool>` to `<codePool>` but the custom class still isn't being used. Finally, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to fix in `config.xml`? Identation?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to enable developer mode first and see the logs also checking if you have defined `<blocks>modulename>class>Yournamespace_yourmodule_Block</class></modulename></blocks>`in your config.xml and case sensitive issue